# Android ViewModel deletes all my data when observing

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-livedata, mutablelivedata

I am developing an app with Android Studio, and I wish to use MutableLiveData alongside with RecyclerView. Problem is, when I add a new item to the MutableLiveData, it gets updated, then going back to the previous fragment, the item gets erased for some unknown reason.
Code in my `FirstFragment.java` for the method `onCreateView`:

```java
@Override
    public View onCreateView(
            LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState
    ) {
        binding = FragmentFirstBinding.inflate(inflater, container, false);

        notificationsViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(requireActivity()).get(NotificationsViewModel.class);

        // Binding recycler views
        // Notifications

        RecyclerView rvNotification = binding.registeredNotification;

        Log.d("NA", "New Adapter");
        NotificationAdapter adapter = new NotificationAdapter();

        Log.d("NA", "Setting adapter");
        rvNotification.setAdapter(adapter);

        Log.d("NA", "Setting layout");
        rvNotification.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));

        Log.d("NA", "Getting the MLD");
        MutableLiveData<List<NotificationContent>> notifs = notificationsViewModel.getNotifications();

        Log.d("NA", "Adding observer");
        notifs.observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<List<NotificationContent>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<NotificationContent> notificationContents) {
                Log.d("ANDROIDAPP", String.format("onChanged: detected and done, item size %d", notificationContents.size()));
                adapter.updateNotifications(notificationContents);
            }
        });

        return binding.getRoot();
    }
```

Code of the `ViewModel` implementation :

```java
public class NotificationsViewModel  extends ViewModel {
    private final MutableLiveData<List<NotificationContent>> notifications = new MutableLiveData<List<NotificationContent>>();

    public MutableLiveData<List<NotificationContent>> getNotifications() {
        if (notifications.getValue() == null) {
            notifications.setValue(new ArrayList<NotificationContent>());
        }
        return notifications;
    }

    public void removeNotification(NotificationContent notificationContent) {
        List<NotificationContent> n = getNotifications().getValue();
        n.remove(notificationContent);
        notifications.setValue(n);
    }

    public void addNotification(NotificationContent notificationContent) {
        List<NotificationContent> n = getNotifications().getValue();
        n.add(notificationContent);
        notifications.setValue(n);
    }

    public void addNotification(int position, NotificationContent notificationContent) {
        List<NotificationContent> n = getNotifications().getValue();
        n.add(position, notificationContent);
        notifications.setValue(n);
    }
}
```

And finally code of the `RecyclerView.Adapter` :

```java
public class NotificationAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NotificationAdapter.ViewHolder> {

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        // View Items declaration...

        public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            // View items retrieval ...
        }
    }

    private List<NotificationContent> mNotifications = new ArrayList<>();

    public void updateNotifications(List<NotificationContent> newNotifications) {
        Log.d("NA", "Clearing");
        this.mNotifications.clear();

        Log.d("NA", "Setting");
        this.mNotifications = newNotifications;

        Log.d("NA", "NotifyChangedDataset");
        this.notifyDataSetChanged();
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        // Some code ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        // Some code ...     
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mNotifications.size();
    }
}
```

To get an idea of the interplay between my fragments here is my `nav_graph.xml` graphical representation :
[image: nav graph in Android Studio capture]

But the problem is that after adding an item through the `addNotificationFragment` it ends up emptying, here is the log from the log given in the code :

```
D/ANDROIDAPP: onViewCreated: addNotification 1
D/ANDROIDAPP: onChanged: detected and done, item size 1
D/NA: Clearing
D/NA: Setting
D/NA: NotifyChangedDataset
D/ANDROIDAPP: onViewCreated: addNotification 2
D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.etilawin.tgvmaxplanner activity: com.etilawin.tgvmaxplanner.MainActivity@df816d4
D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.etilawin.tgvmaxplanner activity: com.etilawin.tgvmaxplanner.MainActivity@df816d4
D/NA: New Adapter
D/NA: Setting adapter
D/NA: Setting layout
D/NA: Item Touche helper
D/NA: Button listener
D/NA: Getting the MLD
D/NA: Adding observer
D/ANDROIDAPP: onChanged: detected and done, item size 0
D/NA: Clearing
D/NA: Setting
D/NA: NotifyChangedDataset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know exactly why but the solution resides in this line :

```java
 notifs.observe(requireActivity(), new Observer<List<NotificationContent>>() {
            ...
        });
```

Here `requireActivity()` is not correct it should be `getViewLifecycleOwner()`.